# OpenCV Seamless Cloning shift position after finish the process

Tags: python-3.x, image-processing, opencv3.0

I am trying to used the seamsless cloning to blend to image together. 
but I notice that after using the seamsless clone function the area in the 
mask that I want to transfer is shift upward. So I have a question that
is this a normal behaviour of the seamsless clone function or it is a bug
on my implementation.

Here are the Source photo

[image]

Here are the destination photo

[image]

Here are the result photo

[image]

Comment: Hello, do you remember if you solved this or what the problem was? I'm facing a similar issue where my source photo is shifted slightly to the left when using seamless cloning. Interestingly, the mask that I use seems to affect this; using an all-white mask will result in no shift.

Answer (score 4):

I encountered similar situation. Moreover, like @JoshuaCWebDeveloper noted, this shift disappeared when all one mask is used. Nevertheless, I got a fix for this. What I did is this. I cropped valid mask (non-zero sub-section) out using `cv2.boundingRect`. So my source image and mask image are reduced to a smaller size, while center is now calculated from boundingRect outputs (Since reference point is marked on destination image). This way, error got solved/shift got ridden.

Answer (score 3):

(Based on the answer posted by Fractalic Forieu) You can achieve the same result without reducing the image size.

Instead of using the image center:

```
center = (width // 2, height // 2)
poissonImage = cv2.seamlessClone(srcImage, dstImage, maskImage, center)
```

use the center of the bounding rect:

```
monoMaskImage = cv2.split(maskImage)[0] # reducing the mask to a monochrome
br = cv2.boundingRect(monoMaskImage) # bounding rect (x,y,width,height)
centerOfBR = (br[0] + br[2] // 2, br[1] + br[3] // 2)
poissonImage = cv2.seamlessClone(srcImage, dstImage, maskImage, centerOfBR )
```